# Primefaces Ajax call from p:selectOneRadio in Primefaces Treetable row not invoke backing bean method

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, treetable

I have the following treetable with nested radio select buttons in one column. Primefaces Ajax tag does partial submit on value change.

```
<p:treeTable value="#{carBean.partsTree}" var="document" id="multiSelect"
             selection="#{carBean.selectedNodes}" selectionMode="single"  >

    <p:column style="width:150px" styleClass="column1asd">
        <f:facet name="header">
            DealerShip                     
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{document.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="width:100px;text-align: center  ">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Car Types
        </f:facet> 
        <h:outputText value="#{document.numCarTypes}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="width:100px;text-align: center">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Contacts
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{document.contactName}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="width:100px;text-align: center">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Contact Emails
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{document.dealerShipContactEmail}" />
    </p:column>


<p:column style="width:100px">
        <f:facet name="header">
                Retail | Commercial | Distribution  
        </f:facet>

    <p:selectOneRadio value="#{document.selectedContactOption}"  >
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Retail"   itemLabel="" style="margin-left:"/> 
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Commercial"  itemLabel="" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Distribution"   itemLabel=""    />
                <p:ajax update=":moreLikeThis:count"   process="@all"  listener="#{dealerShipSelectionBean.updateDetailEvent(e)}" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
</p:column>


    </p:treeTable>
```

Hypothetical data view :

```
Level
R    1    2
|
|    a
-----
|   |
|   |   aa
|   -----
|   |   ab
|   -----
|  
|   b
-----
|   |
|   |   ba
|   -----
|   |   bb
|   -----
|   |   bc
|   -----
|   |   bd
|   -----
|   |   be
|   -----
```

Problem

Ajax call to backing bean method dealerShipSelectionBean.updateDetailEvent(e) is made correctly on every level  1 tree node radio button.

Ajax call to backing bean method dealerShipSelectionBean.updateDetailEvent(e) is made correctly on first level  2 tree node radio button.
Subsequent selection of any other second level treenode radio button where a treenode has been selected from that sub tree previously fires the same (correct ? )  ajax request but does not break into the  backing bean method dealerShipSelectionBean.updateDetailEvent(e)

Eg
select ba - Ajax call to backing bean method .updateDetailEvent(e) is made correctly
select bb - Ajax call made but backing bean method .updateDetailEvent(e) is not called.
select ab - Ajax call to backing bean method .updateDetailEvent(e) is made correctly
select a  - Ajax call to backing bean method .updateDetailEvent(e) is made correctly
select a  - Ajax call to backing bean method .updateDetailEvent(e) is made correctly
select b  - Ajax call to backing bean method .updateDetailEvent(e) is made correctly
select ab - Ajax call made but backing bean method .updateDetailEvent(e) is not called.
select bc - Ajax call made but backing bean method .updateDetailEvent(e) is not called.

Any help greatly appreciated.

primefaces 3.6-SNAPSHOT
mojoraa 2.1.18
tomcat 7